# "Let's get it over (with)" — do I need the "with"?

Tags: phrases, idioms, prepositions, syntactic-analysis

I'm trying to understand why there is this "with". I can say "Let's get this done". So, why "Let's get this over with?"

I would really appreciate if someone could explain that a bit.

Comment: Good question. There doesn't seem to be anything other than established (but inconsistent) idiomatic preference involved in the fact that *with* is usually included in *"Lets get it over"*, but not if we replace *over* with, say, *done* (or any of these other synonyms listed by Merriam Webster: [*completed, concluded, done, down, ended, finished, over, **over with**, terminated, through, up*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/done)).

Comment: (1) The version without the 'with' scores far more Google hits, and is a saying I'm quite familiar with. (2) Good question. I'm wondering whether it's an ellipted form of 'Let's get it over and done with'.

Comment: @Edwin: I rather doubt your point #2, since you don't often hear *"Let's get it **done with.**"*

Comment: @FF: "Let's get it over and done with" and especially "over and done with" are very common on Google. I've not done a study on the preponderance of one out of two apparently equally likely ellipted forms, but I bet it's unpredictable. And 'I'm done with X' is pretty common.

Comment: I'm curious about the syntax. Is there a possibility that the object of a preposition ended up getting fronted, and so, the preposition got stranded? For instance, *"Let's get over this"* -> *"Let's get this over"*, *"Let's get over with this"*" -> *"Let's get this over with"*. -- Just thinkin' out loud without doing any research. . . .

Comment: @F.E. It's a most unusual construction. 'Get X over with' can be near-paraphrased 'get X done' or 'get X out of the way' (with differing connotations of an undesirable task). One seems verbal, the other I'd say adjectival. 'Accomplish X' is also quite close – is this a most unusual type of multi-word verb? Merriam-Webster short-circuits attempts at analysis by classing the string 'over with' as a compound adjective (I'm glad that's now finished / over with). But 'Let's get this over with / finished' seems less adjectival and more a causative or auxiliary + verb structure to me.

Answer (score 4):

It's an idiomatic phrase. Idioms sometimes develop through the strangest manners.
It means to do or finish, especially said of something *unpleasant*.

> You know you need stitches. Let's just get it over with.

[The Atlantic](http://www.theatlantic.com/health/archive/2013/12/just-get-it-over-with/282013/) did a whole article on *getting things over with*.

The first [usage](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/get+over) dates from the 1800s.

> Complete, have done with, especially something unpleasant. For example, When I finally got the proofreading over, I was ready for a day off , or I'm glad to get all that dental work over with . It also is put as ,  as in I might as well sign the check and get it over with .

*The first usage dates from the late 1800s, the second from the early 1800s.*

While most people do say *over with*, it's not necessary. It's very common (in PA, at least) to say *get it over*, *get it done*

Edited to add: A beautiful poem by Philip Larkin (9 August 1922 – 2 December 1985)

> Love, we must part now: do not let it be
>   Calamitious and bitter. In the past
>   There has been too much moonlight and self-pity
>   **Let us have done with it**: for now at last
>   Never has sun more boldly paced the sky
>   Never were hearts more eager to be free
>   To kick down worlds, lash forests; you and I
>   No longer hold them; we are husks, that see
>   The grain going forward to a different use
>
> There is regret. Always, there is regret
>   But it is better that our lives unloose
>   As two tall ships, wind-mastered, wet with light
>   Break from an estuary with their courses set
>   And waving part, and waving drop from sight

Answer (score 1):

Just a hunch here, but it could be because *over* is such a flexible word, so, without the "with," the phrase feels too "open ended." Imagine "Let's get it over," by itself. That could mean:

- We're pushing the car... *Let's get it over the crest of this hill*.
- We're pushing this piano... *Let's get it over there, into the corner*.
- We're baking a plate of cookies... *Let's get it over to the neighbor's, while they're still warm*.
- We're maneuvering a remote control helicopter... *Let's get it over the landing pad*.
- We're taking a test... *Let's get it over with, so we can go home*.